# This program neither reads nor writes to a file

Tags: java, io

**CODE**

```
import java.io.*;
class tester {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
  try {
   FileReader reader = new FileReader(new File("d:\\UnderTest\\check123.txt"));
   FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(new File("d:\\UnderTest\\check123.txt"));
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
   String s;
     while( (s=br.readLine()) != null ) {
       System.out.println(s);
     }
   writer.write("Shadow Shadow");
  } catch(Exception exc) {
     System.out.println(exc);
    }
  }
}
```

This code writes nothing and reads nothing when i run it. Where is the bug in this program ?

Comment: Works fine for me, once the proper closes are in. Without closing the writer, the file contents disappear (on Ubuntu) and will *appear* not to work any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that when you read for first time then content is there in the text file ?
You need to close Reader and Writer in finally block (missing currently in your code) of your try-catch block. closing the stream flushes out content automatically.

Comment: I think closing is the problem too, +1.  Since it's the same file, do you think the OP needs to read fully, then close the reader, and then write and close the writer?

Comment: I think that is the way, first read fully (close the stream also when done) and then write content after you are done reading. And this is what the ultimately the current code looks like to achieve (although written a bit wrongly)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you close the reader and the writer. After using the writer you will need to flush the contents or close the writer (which does the same thing). I tested this and it works.

```
import java.io.*;
class tester {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
  try {
  FileReader reader = new FileReader(new File("c:\\check123.txt"));
  FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(new File("c:\\check123.txt"));
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
  writer.write("Shadow Shadow");     
  writer.close();

  String s;
    while( (s=br.readLine()) != null ) {
      System.out.println(s);
    }
  reader.close();

 } catch(Exception exc) {
    System.out.println(exc);
   }
}
```

}